# Excel VBA - Take only the numeric value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have an IF function in VBA that has a mathematical formula in it:- `(Cells(i3, 10).Value > 30)`

The issue i'm having is that the values in column 10 are all alphanumeric. For example they're all " 1 - Hard", "2 - Moderate", "3 - Easy".

Is there anyway to make VBA only look at the number so when it's testing if the value is more than 30, it actually works?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to parse the string with Left() and Instr() to pull the number.

Comment: `=1*MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(A1,ROW($1:$9),1)))` For cell A1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `val` function should do what you need. It returns the number at the left of a string until a non-number character is found (0 if string contains no number at the left)

```
debug.print val("1 - Hard")   ' prints 1
debug.print val("  31 - Something else")   ' prints 31
debug.print val("123abc")   ' prints 123
debug.print val("x  2 - You name it")   ' prints 0
debug.print val("-31.5.3 - Negative")   ' prints -31.5
```

So just change your if:

```
 if val(Cells(i3, 10).Value) > 30 then
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the left part of the string (before the dash), trim it and convert to `INT`.

```
'item = your cell value
CInt(Trim(Left(item, InStr(1, item, "-") - 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the leading numeric characters from a string using the VBA Val function.

To use this function on a worksheet you will need to create a User Defined Function (UDF) in a standard VBA module.

```
Function LeadingNumbers(Str As String) As Double
    LeadingNumbers = Val(Str)
End Function
```

So in your context use (LeadingNumbers(Cells(i3, 10).Value) > 30).